# URL Schemes in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, url-scheme

I have an iPhone application which I wanted to add URL schemes to. The thing is that I have both a free version and a plus version.

What I would like to do is use the same scheme for both apps, but if the plus version is installed I want to the PLUS version to launch instead of the free version. 
Is that possible?

Br,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. If multiple apps register for the same URL scheme, it is undefined which app will be activated by the OS. From the iOS Application Programming Guide:

> Note: If multiple third-party applications register to handle the same URL scheme, it is undefined as to which of the applications is picked to handle URLs of that type.

*Edit: just a thought how you might work around this issue: have your plus version register a second private URL scheme that you do not publish. Then, if your free app is launched from a URL, have it check whether the plus version is present and forward the passed URL to the plus version (via its private URL scheme).*

Comment: Awesome idea... I'll try with that Idea. For now I have solved it with a webpage showing two buttons "Open in free version" and "open in plus version". Br, Paul Peelen